# Chef - sudo chef-client on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Until yesterday my chef-client was working great.
But today after forcing an install with

```
$ sudo chef-client
```

I get the error below, which looks like the `sudo` recipe is the main reason.

Btw, until yesterday I was running chef client 12.8, so maybe there is something here that I need to check.

I just updated from `sudo` cookbook 2.3 to 2.11 but I'm getting the same thing.

```
$ sudo -V
```

tells me that sudo is already installed so I'm not sure where is the error

```
sudo chef-client
Starting Chef Client, version 12.13.37
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["demo::app"]
...
Recipe: sudo::default
  * apt_package[sudo] action install
================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'apt_package[sudo]'
================================================================================

Errno::ENOMEM
-------------
Cannot allocate memory - fork(2)

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/sudo/recipes/default.rb

 22: package 'sudo' do
 23:   not_if 'sudo -V'
 24: end
 25:

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/sudo/recipes/default.rb:22:in `from_file'

apt_package("sudo") do
  package_name "sudo"
  action [:install]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  default_guard_interpreter :default
  declared_type :package
  cookbook_name "sudo"
  recipe_name "default"
  not_if "sudo -V"
end

Platform:
---------
x86_64-linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you don't have enough memory left. Check other processes.

```
Errno::ENOMEM
-------------
Cannot allocate memory - fork(2)
```

Comment: I did several times $sudo chef-client and the system is no longer responding on bash, as you pointed out it's a memory issue probably caused by chef, since it's the only thing that has changed in the last hours. I'm running a micro instance t2 on AWS. I've rebooted the instance and I'll get back with the results.

Comment: Just have a look at what processes consume your memory.

Comment: Also check your ulimits, might be hitting something weird with nproc.